# SQLAlchemy - How to negate an ANY expression

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using postgres and I'm trying to obtain this raw query using SQLAlchemy expression, but I'm not able to:

```
SELECT foo.id FROM foo WHERE NOT foo.id = ANY('{1,2,3}'::int[]);
```

I tested it with the following table definition:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(80), unique=True)
```

and by running the followings in `IPython`:

```
In [57]: from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import any_, not_

In [58]: from sqlalchemy.dialects import postgresql

In [59]: def compile_(where):
    ...:     statement = select([foo.id, foo.name]).where(where)
    ...:     return str(statement.compile(dialect=postgresql.dialect()))
    ...:

In [60]: where1 = not_(foo.id == any_([1,2,3]))

In [61]: compile_(where1)
Out[61]: 'SELECT foo.id, foo.name \nFROM foo \nWHERE foo.id != ANY (%(param_1)s)'
```

As you can see, instead of obtaining `WHERE NOT foo.id != ANY(...)` I get `WHERE foo.id != ANY(...)`.

**NOTES**:

I'm aware of `IN` and `NOT IN`, but I cannot use them due to the length of `other` which is `> 32767` and this causes an `InterfaceError` due to the number of bind arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems SQLAlchemy tries to be too smart. You can outsmart it not using `NOT`:

```
where1 = foo.id != all_([1,2,3]))
```